Failed opening 'db.php' for inclusion error when executed from root directory
I am trying to run a PHP script (xyz.php) that is stored in /var/www/html from the command line by using the command:
sudo php /var/www/html/xyz.php

This script has an include statement in it:
 include('db.php')

When run from outside /var/www/html, it is not working and giving me an error:
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on numm in /var/www/html/xyz.php

The warning message is:
include(): Failed opening 'db.php' for inclusion (include_path = '.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/xyz.php

It works fine when executed from /var/www/html but I have a cronjob and I need to run it from outside of /var/www/html
The include_path entry in my php.ini looks like:
.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php

Where am I going wrong with this? This is Amazon Linux 2

The relative path in the include evaluates as relative to where php is executing from, not relative to the script the include is in.  So if you run php /var/www/html/xyz.php from /home/jane, it will expect db.php to be at /home/jane/db.php.  You could use a fully qualified path for the include, or better, run it from the docroot PHP would normally be in, cd to the right place first: cd /var/www/html && sudo php /var/www/html/xyz.php.

When using the include keyword, if your included script is in the same directory, it would be ideal to prefix the file name with __DIR__.
__DIR__ evaluates to the path of the file it is used on. So when __DIR__ is called inside xyz.php, it will evaluate to the directory xyz.php is in
So do
include __DIR__ . '/db.php';

Even if the file is in different directories, you can still use __DIR__
For example, if your structure was like this instead
/var/www
  + html
    - xyz.php
  - db.php

You could use __DIR__ like so
include __DIR__ . '/../db.php';

